# Error: Cannot resolve type entity i2.ExtensionsModule to symbol

Tags: angular, upgrade, angular.json, tsconfig.json

I am upgrading Angular 5.x to 15.x.

I have resolved most build errors except this -

```
    ./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Cannot resolve type entity i2.ExtensionsModule to symbol

./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Cannot resolve type entity i2.ExtensionsModule to symbol
```

I have tried adding  "preserveSymlinks": true in my angular.json file but it didn't help.

I also tried adding

```
  "paths": {
    "@syncfusion/*": [
      "./node_modules/@syncfusion/*"
    ],
  }
```

to my tsconfig.json file with no luck. any pointer in solving this issue is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

installing  "intl": "1.2.5" fixed my problem.

Add dependency  "intl": "1.2.5" to your package.json